# How to retrieve mime type for the current get attachment

Tags: wordpress, mime-types, attachment

I'm uploading some pdf files and .doc/docx files in a project.
So, I'm inserting a link attachment file inside the loop and is working fine.

But I need to get a specific attribute: the mimetype.

So, I need to print the attachment url and mimetype, like this

Download file on http://domain.com/wp-content/...file.pdf
File Type: pdf or application/pdf

Could someone help me with this?

By the way, I´m using a custom theme and not the default wordpress theme.

Thanks a lot.

Flávio

Answer (score 6):

There is a function for that

```
echo get_post_mime_type();
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are indeed dealing with an attachment post type inside the loop, you should be able to access the post_mime_type:

```
global $post;
$mime_type = $post->post_mime_type;
```

`global $post` may already be set, but if not, it is necessary in order to access the post data.

Comment: Hi Sardine,I looked into media.php file at line 911, and I got success using this:

<li> Download File: 
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'numberposts' => -1, 'post_status' => null, 'post_parent' => $post->ID ); $attachments = get_posts($args);
if ($attachments) {
foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
the_attachment_link( $attachment->ID , false );
}
}
?>
</li>
<li>File Type:  <?php echo $attachment->post_mime_type; ?></li> 

Tks for your help